# iOS app does not show the previous edit message when re-editing during grace period

Tags: bug, ios-app

I created revision 3 of the revisions for https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44677711/revisions using an iPhone and the iOS app.  I did it in two steps.  For the first step, I noted the significant changes in the comment ("Remove thanks and where").  For the second step, within a minute or so, I made a couple of other grammatical changes I'd missed first time around.

The iOS app did not show the original change text on the re-edit, unlike the browser version of SO which does.  And somehow it decided that the comment should be the end result "Remove thanks and where; added 4 characters in body".

I think that there are two bogus aspects to this:

1. No showing the previous edit message by default when re-editing.
2. Magically adding unhelpful text to a previous edit message despite not showing the previous message.

Desired fix:

1. The app should show the previous edit message if you re-edit a posting within the grace period.
2. It shouldn't add the "added N characters" message to the previous message.